# How to make correct revert to specific version in django-reversion?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-reversion

I have 2 question cause little bit comfused with [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) app. I have page where users can see list all of reversions. Every version has button to revert.

**1 Question**: How to show only some fields of changes. Right now it shows me all fields. I use version.field_dict.items.

**2 Question**: How to make correct revert to specific version?

Here below you can see code but it raise Error in views.py when I try to click to revert link. What I did wrong?

**template.html**

```
{% for version in versions %}
       {% for field_name, field_value in version.field_dict.items %}
             {{ field_name }}
             {{ field_value }}
       {% endfor %}
       <a href="{% url 'project:group_task_revert' project_code=project.code group_task_code=group_task.code group_task_reversion_id=version.revision.id%}">REVERT</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py:**

```
 url(r'^(?P<project_code>[0-9a-f-]+)/(?P<group_code>[0-9a-f-]+)/(?P<group_reversion_id>\d+)/$',
        group_revert,
        name='group_revert'),
```

**views.py:**

```
def group_revert(request, project_code, group_code, group_reversion_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_code, status='open')
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=group_code)

    versions = Version.objects.get_for_object(group)
    versions[group_reversion_id].revision.revert()

    return redirect('project:project_detail', project_code=project.code)
```

**ERROR:**

```
Internal Server Error: /ru/account/dashboard/projects/42442299-97dd-4d92-9ef1-880f9cdd1612/4d3d3422-2618-4d66-96f5-8f0a0b5d9bf3/21/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\PycharmProjects\RMS\project\views.py", line 198, in group_revert
    versions[group_reversion_id].revision.revert()
  File "C:\Users\Nurzhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 271, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question: [dhango-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/issues/635)